# unable to dismiss progressDialog inside Activity

Tags: android, progressdialog

Sorry I know this question has been asked several time and has lots of answer but none of them solved my problem. 
I'm calling web service and showing dialog, which is working ok. But I'm unable to dismiss the progressDialog. Although the same method is working inside fragment but this time I'm using it in Activity. Please point me where I'm making the mistake.

```
    public void signupServiceResponse(String phNum,String password){
    progressDialog = createProgressDialog(this, false);
    //progressDialog.show();
    final ContentServiceCall request = ServiceGenerator.createService(ContentServiceCall.class, "Empty");
    final Call<UserServiceResponse> call = request.signUp(Constants.WS_VERSION,Constants.LOCAL_EN,Constants.PLATFORM, phNum,password);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<UserServiceResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UserServiceResponse> call, final Response<UserServiceResponse> response) {
            if(response!=null && response.isSuccessful())
            {
                if(response.body()!=null && response.body().getResponse()!=null)
                {
                    if(response.body().getResponse().getResponseCode()== Constants.RESPONSE_CODE_SUCCESS) {

                        if(response.body().getUser() != null && response.body().getUserSubscription()!= null && response.body().getUserSubscription() !=null) {

                            userEntity = response.body().getUser();
                            userProfileEntity = response.body().getUserProfile();
                            userSubscriptionEntity = response.body().getUserSubscription();
                            //insert in user table
                            int tableCode = 1; //table code 1 for user table
                            dbHelper.insertUserRegistration(userEntity, userProfileEntity, userSubscriptionEntity, tableCode);
                            dbHelper.close();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Intent i = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, ActivateAccountActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }

                    } else if((response.body().getResponse().getResponseCode()== Constants.USERAlREADYEXIST_RESPONSE_CODE_SUCCESS)) {
                        // in case user data is cleared or app is reinstalled
                        boolean userCount = dbHelper.getUserCount();
                        if (userCount) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);

                        } else if(!userCount){
                            // if user exist and data is cleared
                            userEntity = response.body().getUser();
                            userProfileEntity = response.body().getUserProfile();
                            userSubscriptionEntity = response.body().getUserSubscription();
                            int tableCode = 1;
                            dbHelper.insertUserRegistration(userEntity, userProfileEntity, userSubscriptionEntity, tableCode);
                            dbHelper.close();
                        }

                    } else if((response.body().getResponse().getResponseCode()== Constants.RESPONSE_CODE_PASSWORD_INCORRECT)){
                        Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this,"Password incorrect",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        btnForgetPassword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    else {
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // leave it
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Display proper message
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),getString(R.string.error_webservice_response),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UserServiceResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            Log.e("Fail", "Failure");
            Log.e("ERROR", t.getMessage());
                progressDialog.dismiss();
              Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this,getString(R.string.error_internet_connectivity),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

public ProgressDialog createProgressDialog(Context mContext, Boolean cancelable) {
    final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    try {
        dialog.show();
    } catch (WindowManager.BadTokenException e) {

    }
    dialog.setCancelable(cancelable);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: This is usually because `progressDialog` no longer points to the instance you think it does when `dismiss()` is called. Instead of a class field for `progressDialog`, make `final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ...` right there in `signupServiceResponse()`. Also, make sure you aren't actually ending up with multiple visible instances. That is, make sure you're not inadvertently calling `signupServiceResponse()` more than once.

Comment: only calling signupServiceResponse() once. and I have declared progressDialog globally like this. ProgressDialog progressDialog = null. Should I remove that?

Comment: Your `progressDialog` variable refers to the `ProgressDialog` returned by the method `createProgressDialog` and not `android.app.ProgressDialog`. This is the reason why your dismiss() methods don't work.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to remove the field declaration, if you're gonna use it. I'm just saying that you need to make sure that you're dismissing the right instance. To test your current situation, try it with a `final` local instance there in that method.

Comment: @SrikarReddy That doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: @MikeM. I declared it like this in Response method final  ProgressDialog progressDialog = createProgressDialog(this, false); but the still the same problem.

Comment: Are you certain `dismiss()` is actually getting called? Are you certain you don't have multiple dialogs showing on top of each other?

Comment: yes I debugged and checked that dismiss is getting called.

Comment: @MikeM. I removed the progress dialog initialization from the CreateDialog method and created its object in onCreate, and it worked. you were right the response method is being calling twice I don't know why. Any way thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `dialog` a global variable and initialize it in the `onCreate()` (If you're inside an Activity).

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
```

Add this method.

```
public ProgressDialog dismiss() {
    if(dialog != null) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Finally, instead of calling `progressDialog.dismiss()` simply call `dismiss()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check /write like this.

if(progressDialog!=null &&
 progressDialog.isshowing){

```
   progressDialog.dismiss();
```

}

I am using and it is working.

Comment: Check like this